# MyBatis is looking for org/hsqldb/DatabaseURL while I set for MmySQL

Tags: java, mysql, guice, hsqldb, mybatis

I steup a sample project with Maven3/Guice/MyBatis3.1 and using "jdbc:mysql://..."

but when I want to call the mapper methods( mapper.getBean() ) I am getting :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hsqldb/DatabaseURL
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:191)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.doGetConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:186)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSource.getConnection(UnpooledDataSource.java:88)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.popConnection(PooledDataSource.java:373)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource.getConnection(PooledDataSource.java:82)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.openConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:131)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:58)

Comment: Is org/hsqldb/DatabaseURL on your classpath?

Comment: no, but why ? I am using mysql not hsqldb !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the library containing `org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL` is on your `classpath`

Comment: Why? I am using mysql not hsqldb, it is mandatory for all drivers ?!

Comment: I am not familiar with MyBatis. If all is self contained, perhaps org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL loads an appropriate driver given some jdbc url (this is a wild guess). Ultimately, the infrastructure is looking for org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL, thus it needs to be on your classpath. If you are sure org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL is not required, perhaps you have some configuration problem.

Comment: I checked my configs it seems okay,

Comment: I also followed guice configuration page and there is just a dependency for MyBatis in maven nothing more